# Why does my environment variable affect the execution of an SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, environment-variables

I am learning Powershell by my own and I am trying to keep the best practices in my learning process. I am using a database.env file with some key value pair configuration lines, if I use it I present the error, if I put it on plain text to the code, it does work and I do not know why.

**The error:**

> PS C:\Path\To\Folder> .\main.ps1
> Connected to the database: MY_INSTANCE on server: MY_DATABASE
> "SELECT table_schema, table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE';"
> Error: Exception calling "Fill" with "1" argument(s): "Could not find stored procedure 'SELECT table_schema, table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE';'."

It tells me "Could not find stored procedure ...", but I am not using any, since my command type is ""Text" as it is mentioned below ( $command.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::Text ).

1- This is my database.env file content:

```
# database.env

# Configuration
DATABASE_DEFAULT_SERVER_INSTANCE="MY_INSTANCE"
DATABASE_DEFAULT_NAME="MY_DATABASE"
DATABASE_DEFAULT_USERNAME="MY_USER"
DATABASE_DEFAULT_PASSWORD="MY_PASSWORD"

# QUERIES
SELECT_INFORMATION_SCHEMA="SELECT table_schema, table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE';"
```

2- This is my main.ps1 file code:

```
# main.ps1

. .\src\Functions\StartEnvVariables.ps1
Start-EnvVariables

Import-Module .\src\Modules\Database\DBFunctions.psd1
Import-Module .\src\Modules\StoredProcedures\CreateProcedures.psd1

$connection = Get-Connection
    
try {
    $connection.Open()
    
    Write-Host "Connected to the database: $($connection.Database) on server: $($connection.DataSource)"

    # ✔️ Works fine
    # With burnt content
    #$query = "SELECT table_schema, table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE';"

    # ✖️ Does not work
    # With environment variable
    $query = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("SELECT_INFORMATION_SCHEMA")

    Write-Host $query
    $command = $connection.CreateCommand()
    $command.CommandText = $query
    $command.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::Text

    $adapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter $command
    $dataTable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
    $adapter.Fill($dataTable)

    foreach ($row in $dataTable.Rows) {
        $schema = $row["table_schema"]
        $tableName = $row["table_name"]

        Start-CreateProcedures -SchemaName $schema -TableName $tableName
    }
}
catch {
    Write-Host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)"
}
finally {
    $connection.Close()
}
```

3- And this is how I load the environment variables:

```
function Start-EnvVariables {
    Get-Content .\config\database.env | ForEach-Object {
        $indexOfEquals = $_.IndexOf('=')
        if ($indexOfEquals -ge 0) {
            $name = $_.Substring(0, $indexOfEquals).Trim()
            $value = $_.Substring($indexOfEquals + 1).Trim()
            
            [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable($name, $value, [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Process)
        }
    }
}
```

1- I tried converting my environment variable content to string:

```
$query = ([System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("SELECT_INFORMATION_SCHEMA")).toString()
```

2- To verify the single quotes are not affecting at the SQL execution:

"SELECT table_schema, table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE';"
"SELECT table_schema, table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_type = '''BASE TABLE''';"

Comment: what's the output of `$query = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("SELECT_INFORMATION_SCHEMA")`?

Comment: This:

`Write-Host $query`

Output: 

"SELECT table_schema, table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE';"

Comment: it returns it with the double quotes?

Comment: Yes, it does my friend. Since it is a string, the normal I guess

Comment: try `$query = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("SELECT_INFORMATION_SCHEMA") -replace '"'`. The output of a string, unless otherwise specified, should just be the text. It shouldn't be displayed to the console with quotes around it as it's already a string.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate the solution [Abraham Zinala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14903754/abraham-zinala) shared with me.

It seems the environment variable was including the double quotes (""), so it was not the query SQL Server was expecting for...

The solution was to add `-replace '"'` at the end of the line, so the double quotes were removed

```
$query = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("SELECT_INFORMATION_SCHEMA") -replace '"'
```

Comment: Ultimately, it would benefit you using the removal of the double-quotes when you load the environment variables into your session with `Start-EnvVariables`. Preferably: `$value = $_.Substring($indexOfEquals + 1).Trim() -Replace '"'`. It just wouldn't account for other values that would need those quotes in there. That way you could just call `$query = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("SELECT_INFORMATION_SCHEMA")` normally.